# Is there any way to know if any device is connect to com1 (RS-232)?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to know if any device is connect to com1 (RS-232) ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell directly, only indirectly via checking for a signal as Matthew has stated.

As well as DCD, the DTR and DSR signals are commonly used for this as a form of handshake, where each device raises the DTR line and connects it to the DSR input of the dvice it is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, from my time working with serial devices, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232), the closest you can get is checking the carrier detect (DCD) signal. [This article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx) may come in handy if you're doing RS-232 programming. It specifically has a FAQ section which answers "*How do you detect when a device is connected or disconnected?*"